# Formatting model.DateTimeField in a dataTables

Tags: javascript, django, datatables

I can't figure out how to format the datetime that I'm getting out of Django models.DateTimeField.

The output of the data is: 2019-04-10T21:23:47-05:00.
I want the output to be: 04-10-2019

I have tried using:

```
columnDefs: [
        {
            targets: 1,
            "width": "20%", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment( 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss-hh:mm' 'Do MMM YYYYY' )
        }
    ],
```

It's not working.  Without the render, the row displays fine, but with the date timestamp as it is above.  But once I had the render, the row doesn't display.

Comment: why don't you format the time in Django?

Comment: I suppose I could, but I still want the time in the data for sorting.  I just want to format it for the user

Comment: Format your datetime in Django Ex: field_name.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")